# Import a python module existing in directory A into another module in directory B

Tags: python, import, python-import, python-module

I have this module named say `a.py` in the directory `/home/ssridhar/Python`. This module contains a function say

```
def number_haloes(n):
    halo_param = var2['halo_id'][z1]
    print len(halo_param)
```

I have another module say `b.py` in the directory `/home/ssridhar/Python/mean`.

I want to use the `def number_haloes` from `a.py` in `b.py`

I tried `import a` but it is showing **ImportError: No module named a**

How do I do this task?

Comment: I believe you can use ```__import__()``` to specify the full path and file name

Comment: @wnnmaw should i say __import__(/home/ssridhar/Python/a.py) ??

Comment: It would be ```a = __import__(r"/home/ssridhar/Python/a.py")``` I think, but you should read [the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#__import__) to double check

Comment: But you might be better off throwing ```os.path.abspath()``` around your name to avoid complications

Comment: doesn't this solves the issue: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631/how-to-import-a-module-given-the-full-path?rq=1

Comment: @Svend Yep, and this is probably a dupe, good find

Comment: @wnnmaw but when I follow the answer there, it runs my a.py!! I only want to use the def inside a.py

Answer (score 0):

You need to add "/home/ssridhar/Python" to your python path. Only then Python will know how to load a.py. For instance you can try this

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/home/ssridhar/Python')

import a
```

Comment: when I try this, this runs my a.py!! I only want to use the def inside a.py

Comment: unless there is a call to the function in a.py it won't get executed. Can you post what all is there in a.py.

Comment: well it is a big program! But what it does it, it takes two files, compares them with some input conditions and writes out several files according to the conditions.. This def inside the function, just tells me how many files are there in each file being written

Comment: What I mean is in a.py if you are calling `number_haloes(n)` then it will get executed every time a gets imported. You can try to add the function calls under an if condition for instance- `if __name__ == "__main__": number_haloes(n)` [read](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do)

Comment: This will stop the function from executing if `a` is getting imported in an another module.